# What is the colon operator in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, operators

You always see code like

```
project(':bluewhale').hello
```

This doesn't seem to be Groovy syntax, what is it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The colon is not an operator (you can see it's being used inside a string). It's the separator that Gradle uses to describe paths to subprojects. For example,

```
evaluationDependsOn(':api:producer')
```

would look for the subproject `producer` of the subproject `api`.

Comment: For those like me who were looking for the meaning of the colon _when executing a task_, this is explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426354/2520643