# why cant I run tasks in gradle using colons as the path to root?

Tags: java, gradle

I found a curious thing while building some ci pipelines on a multi project repo using gradle...

As you know, in a multi project repo, you can either run tasks (lets do `test`) on all projects by:

```
./gradlew test
```

or run the task specifying the path from root, with `:` being root like so:

```
./gradlew :project:test
```

good! now, Im baffled as to why we cant use `./gradlew :test` as an alias of `./gradlew test`

it makes sense in my mind, colons is just root. in my case, it would have been easier for my CI pipelines to concat whatever submodule to `:` instead of having to strip it or have the colon as input.

even more fun, intellij seems to have the exact same issue when running tests using the UI, it generates `:test` and breaks forcing me to either fix it manually or use the terminal.

Now my questions:

- am I missing something? maybe its a config thing on my side but couldnt find anything
- if not, why was gradle designed like this? feels weird

**EDIT:**
Im getting the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'test' not found in root project
```

Comment: What's the error? It's supposed to work - doing :test behaves the same as test - at least when I have that task defined in the project and all the subprojects. It fails if there's no named task in the parent project

Comment: Thanks @AnyaShenanigans! just updated the question with the error. I guess it would work if I create a `test` task in root but I expected to work by default since I wish to run any generic multiproject gradle on my ci pipeline without further code config

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394617/why-is-there-a-difference-between-gradlew-clean-build-and-gradlew-clean-bui/53426354#53426354) I think explains what's happening more clearly. Essentially `:test` requires it in the root, while `test` invokes it everywhere it can be found

Comment: Absolutely! answers the question! thanks! seems like its designed on purpose to be able to have custom root tasks. still would expect a well known task like `test` or `build` to run on all subprojects if undefined